# crontab not working for deleting a old files from log folder

Tags: cron, find, chmod

I have this line in my crontab to delete old files:

```
1 * * * * find /var/log/abc/ -mtime +7 -type f -delete
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

I have attempted to give all users permission to clear that folder using

```
chmod +777 /var/log/abc
```

But the chmod did not work. What else could I try?

---

Following the suggestions to log the output, I am finding that this is in the logs:

```
/bin/sh: 1: find: not found
```

So I think I need to set my path correctly...

Comment: You could add `> /var/tmp/out 2>&1` and then look at that file for what errors are being generated

Comment: Try running the command manually and see if it throws some errors.`find /var/log/abc/ -mtime +7 -type f -delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a good practice add the user who is going to execute this crontab.

```
1 *    * * *   root    find /var/log/abc/ -mtime +7 -type f -delete
```

Did you proved that the find is working properly outside of cron?

Try to execute it manually and see what happens, there's nothing wrong with cron.

As a second good practice try to log what cron does to syslog for example using logger:

```
1 *    * * *   root    find /var/log/abc/ -mtime +7 -type f -delete 2>&1 | logger -t cron_find_delete
```

The

> 2>&1

at the end is going to throw sterr and stdout to the logger.